# multiply elements in array list by vector using loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, numpy-ndarray, matrix-multiplication

```
list_of_arrays = [a,[split[12]]]
a = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2000, 0 ,0])
resultnew = []
output = a
for i in list_of_arrays[1:]:
    output = output@i        
    resultnew.append(output)
```

I need help I am trying to multiply a by an array list containing 50 16x16 matrices.Example starting from split[12] (the 13th matrix in the list) , multiplied by a, and then taking the result and multiplying it by split[13], continuing until split[50] is reached.I need the output appended for each iterration.

Comment: What you have shown is a bit roundabout, but it should still work. Are you getting any errors?  If so, please share them.

Comment: ` TypeError: Object arrays are not currently supported `  from the @sign. When I use np.dot, it only gives me the array of a * split[12] as the output, how can I edit the loop to give me each array (previous product * split) until split[50] is reached, is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are using an older version of `numpy` that doesn't support the `@` (`matmul`) operator, which leads to the error.  Or maybe your arrays are somehow python objects, not numbers (you don't show enough code for me to guess why).

If your `numpy` versions supports `@`, the following should work:

```py
output = a
for arr in split[12:51]:
    output = output@arr
    resultnew.append(output)
```

If not, you could explicitly use [`matmul`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html#numpy.matmul):

```py
output = np.matmul(output, arr)
```